# Getting reference from directive scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div some-directive ng-model="some-directive-scope.variable>
    {{ some-directive-scope.variable }}
  </div>
  <p ng-bind="some-directive-scope.variable"></p>
</div>
```

I'm using a third party library which doesn't give me access to a particular directive scoped variable. Is there a way that my controller could grab the reference or set a value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init` to bind it to a variable defined in the outer-scope. E.g.:

Controller:

```
function myController($scope) {
    //Due to inheritance rules between scopes we must place the scope variable
    //in a container and not directly on the scope, otherwise it won't work
    $scope.scopes = {};
}
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div some-directive ng-model="some-directive-scope.variable" ng-init="scope.some-directive = some-directive-scope">
    {{ some-directive-scope.variable }}
  </div>
  <p ng-bind="scopes.some-directive.variable"></p>
</div>
```